# Use Tor browser to download in .com site

Tags: tor, anonymity

I'm using Tor browser to download a file from a .com website. Can the website track/identify my original IP address.

Does Tor hide real my IP address during the download ?

Comment: Yes, Tor hides your IP address. However the file may very well be malicious and since you'll open it outside of Tor it may leak your public IP address *and* prove that both the Tor exit node and your real IP are yours, thus blowing up your anonymity.

Answer (score -2):

Tor hide your identity, hide your ip and Tor is much safe. Anyway. 
Teorically anyone can found your real IP with a virus/malware, the real ip can be found with exit node.

Comment: I don't quite think that the user expected a "yes" answer. Some of your facts lack detail